# a matching word function with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I am trying to write some code that will match words typed into a text input with words in div's with the class 'searchable' and highlights these words. What I have now works if one or more word matches and there are no words which don't match. For example, if the searchable div had the phrase: `hello world` and in the input was `hello world` it would highlight both. If the input had just `hello`, it would highlight that word. But if the input had `hello mars`, it would not highlight the word `hello`, because `mars` is not in the string. this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ptv5N/) demonstrates this. Any ideas much appreciated. Here is the code. Thank you.

javaScript:

```
if($('#search').val().length !== 0){

   $('.searchable').each(function(){

   var search_value = $("#search").val();
   var search_regexp = new RegExp(search_value, "g");

   $(this).html($(this).html().replace(search_regexp,"<span class ='highlight'>"+search_value+"</span>"));

  });
}
```

html:

```
<input type = "text" id = "search" value = "hello mars">
<div class = "searchable">hello world</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446170/escape-string-for-use-in-javascript-regex
String.prototype.pregQuote = function()
{
  return this.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&");
};

var keyword = $("#search").val();
var searchRegex = new RegExp( '(' + keyword.pregQuote() + ')' , "ig" );

$('.searchable').each(function(){
  var html = $(this).html();
  html = html.replace( searchRegex , '<span class="highlight">$1</span>');
  $(this).html( html );
});
```